# I want to make a call to a php function within my javascript code, but I get a sytax error

Tags: php, javascript

POST_manip.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // get the post vars
            var $_POST = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
            document.write($_POST);
```

I'm just trying to manipulate post vars with javascript, but first, I need those vars, and php is the only way to do it.

Comment: I do not really know what you are trying to do.. :) maybe you can supply more information :)

Comment: What do you get when you view source on the outputted page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_encode returns a valid js object, not an string, so you can access your js $_POST as a regular object.

are .html files parsed thru PHP in your server? try changing the file extension to .php

you can use console.log($_POST) and something like firebug instead of document.write() to check the variable contents

Comment: in a .php file, can I still do <script> tags?

Comment: Yes. You can do anything you can do in a .html file, with the addition of PHP functionallity. PHP treats anything outside the `<?php ?>` tags as data to write straight to the browser.

Comment: aye, converting to php, did the trick. Also, for the specific task I'm doing (form redirection, jQuery doesn't work across different sites... so.. we'll see if php can solve that problem)